# safe way of allocating memory for a list node

Tags: c, memory-management, list, portability

In a simple list, ex :

```
struct Node {  
    Node *next;  
    void *data;  
}
```

is there any problem if i allocate Node and Data in a single allocation (provided i know the size), like

```
Node * t = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node) + DataSize));
```

and always assign data at the end of allocated chunk,

```
t->data = (BYTE*)t+ sizeof(Node); /* BYTE is byte length, can use char in gcc */
```

Node and data will get deleted in a sinlge go, so there no real problem tighlty coupling them (by design )

I am looking at Portability issues (specifically with Packing) or other unknown issues ?

Is this way of allocation safe and portable ?

Answer (score 4):

As dirkgently said, don't case the return of `malloc()` in C, doing so is useless and can hide errors.

Also, to compute the address following the Node header, I find it cleaner to do it like this:

```
t->data = t + 1;
```

This works because `t` is a typed pointer, so arithmetic on it works fine. Adding one increments it by the size of the pointed-to data, i.e. `sizeof (Node)` in this case. I find this usage idiomatic for this particular case, of computing the address immediately following something just `malloc()`ed (when that "something" is a well-defined type with a statically known size, as the `Node` struct in this case, of course).

This has the following benefits:

- No repetition of the type name.
- No `sizeof`, so shorter.
- Again, no cast.
- Very simple arithmetic involved, easy to read.

I realized there's an error with your use of the `Node` type before it's properly declared, too. I don't agree with dirkgently's solution, here's how it should look, in C:

```
/* This introduces the type name "Node", as an alias for an undefined struct. */
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
  Node *next; /* This is OK, the compiler only needs to know size of pointer. */
  void *data;
};
```

For completeness, and since I never tire of showing how I consider code like this should be written, here's an example of a function to create a new node to hold n bytes of data:

```
Node * node_new(size_t n)
{
  Node *node;

  if((node = malloc(sizeof *node + n)) != NULL)
  {
    node->next = NULL;
    node->data = node + 1;
  }
  return node;
}
```

That's it. Note use of `sizeof` on the *pointer target* in the `malloc()` call, to avoid repeating the type name and making an easy-to-forget dependency if the type should ever change.

Comment: Well, he did say portable .. and if a c++ compiler is going to chew on it, the return of malloc has to be cast.

Comment: Well .. I would never consider that a case of the code being "portable". Writing C to compile as C++ is not writing portable C, it's something completely different. Portable to me means "possible to compile with other C compilers", not relying on architecture details, and so on.

Comment: @unwind: Which part do you find disagreeable?

Comment: @dirkgently: You still use the Node type before the typedef is complete. Your code doesn't compile, at least not with gcc.

Comment: @unwind: Updated. Foxed by comeau though which accepts it in both C89/90 and C99 mode. Time to dig in the C99 specs.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, it's could be unsafe if the data has alignment requirements. malloc() returns a pointer suitably aligned for all types, and it's likely that `t+1` is also aligned. Likely, but not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `Node` as a type until you create an alias. Use:

```
typedef struct Node {
   struct Node* n;
   void* data;
}Node;
```

No need to cast the result of `malloc` if you are going to stick to a C compiler. I find the following easier to maintain and read:

```
Node* t = malloc(sizeof *t + DataSize);
```

`BYTE` is not a standard type defined by the language and hence *unportable*. What does the following line try to accomplish?

```
t->data = (BYTE*)t+ sizeof(Node);
```

If you want to assign something, the following suffices:

```
t->data = pointer to some data ...
```

If you want to get the byte offset use `offsetof` macro.

Packing is implementation specific. You have to refer the appropriate compiler documentation and see what is available to you.

Additionally, you may want to have a `head` object that maintains some housekeeping information about the list (length etc).

Comment: I guess you need to cast for allocations that point to non void* types. 
BYTE/char is needed for proper pointer addition.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @MSalters. As long as you have a level of indirection (the `data` pointer), you might as well do the proper thing and allocate a separate block for it.

Now, an alternative would be using a *flexible array member* defined in C99:

```
typedef struct Node {
    struct Node *next;
    char data[];
} Node;

Node *n = malloc(sizeof(*n) + DataSize * sizeof(*data));
//if (n != NULL), access data[0 ~ DataSize-1]
```

`sizeof(struct Node)` is supplemented with an appropriate amount of padding (if any) such that the alignment requirements of `data` are met, and `data[]` acts as if it was declared as an array of the maximum possible size that would fit the memory block returned by `malloc()`. This goes for all types of `data`, not just `char` (hence the second `sizeof`).